# Automating Google App Engine Uploads

Tags: java, google-app-engine, upload

I'm trying to automate the upload of a google app engine (java) project, there's not problem using the ant macros to upload to a single user+password combination as after the first manual login through appcfg but when I want to switch to another account I need to re-input the password through the stdin in appcfg.

I don't seem to be able to find a way to pass the password as a switch to appcfg only the username has anyone successfully automated this process or have any ideas on how to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell appcfg to read your password from standard input by passing the `--passin` switch.   Then you can redirect standard input to read your password from a file like this to avoid having appcfg prompt you for anything:

```
appcfg.py update /path/to/my/app --email=me@xyz.com --passin < /path/to/my/pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's OAuth2 with `appcfg.sh`.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Passwordless_Login_with_OAuth2